# insert data from one excel file to another one using ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to insert data from one excel file to another one using `adodb` and faced a problem with insert method. It gives me an error message like below:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

I tried different date formats, with and without quotes, also I tried different method with record sets and still got the same problem with this sql statement.
Can someone help me to find out what's the problem?

```
Public Sub InsertIntoTable() 

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


objConnection.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\User1\Documents\Excel files\tracker.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""


mySQL = "INSERT INTO ResourceTasks (Name, Task, Date, Load) VALUES ('Name11', 'task2'," & CDate("24 / 5 / 2017") & ", 0.50)"

Debug.Print mySQL

objConnection.Execute mySQL

End Sub
```

This code I use to get Name from ResourceTasks and load it into master page; with very similar functions I retrieve tasks, load and dates the only difference it's a formatting on the screen

I made my connection with next parameters : adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

```
Public Sub SearchNames()

Dim oResources As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oDal As New clsDAL

Worksheets("Master").Activate

Set oResources = oDal.GetReadonlyRS("SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [ResourceTasks$]") 'where Date >= **Drop date from selection here**  and Date < **Drop date from selection here**  'where Active like TRUE ")

oResources.MoveFirst

'get all record from record set one by one to 2nd table

Do Until oResources.EOF
    RowNumber = 30 + oResources.AbsolutePosition
    Range("A" & RowNumber).Value = oResources.Fields("Name").Value 
    oResources.MoveNext
Loop

'! get all record from record set one by one to 2nd table

'Close connection and file

oResources.Close

Set oResources = Nothing

oDal.closeFile

Set oDal = Nothing

'! close connection and file

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: As a suggestion, you should use `Option Explicit` to force yourself to declare all your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found it's easier for me to AddNew than to Insert for some reason
It looks like this; hope it would help someone

```
Public Function InsertNewRecord() As Boolean

Dim oTasks As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oDal As New clsDAL

Set oTasks = oDal.GetUpdateableRS("SELECT * FROM [ResourceTasks$] WHERE Task=''")

With oTasks
    .AddNew
        .Fields("Name").Value = Sheets("Master").ComboBox24.Value 
        .Fields("Task").Value = Sheets("Master").ComboBox25.Value 
        .Fields("Date").Value = Sheets("Master").ComboBox23.Value
        .Fields("Load").Value = Sheets("Master").TextBox24.Value 
    .Update
    .Close
End With

Set oTasks = oDal.GetUpdateableRS("SELECT Task FROM [Tasks$] WHERE Task=''")

With oTasks
    .AddNew
        .Fields("Task").Value = sTask
    .Update
    .Close
End With

Set oDal = Nothing
Set oTasks = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this running your query against a recordset and then copying it to your target range. Code would be like:

```
Public Sub InsertIntoTable()

    Dim objConnection As Object
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConnection.Open _
        "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\User1\Documents\Excel files\tracker.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""

    Dim mySQL As String
    mySQL = "INSERT INTO ResourceTasks (Name, Task, Date, Load) VALUES ('Name11', 'task2'," & CDate("24 / 5 / 2017") & ", 0.50)"

    Debug.Print mySQL

    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rs.Open mySQL, objConnection

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset Data:=rs

End Sub
```

Regards

*** EDIT ***
From post update from OC. Note that I am unfamiliar with command `clsDAL` so I have only edited copying recordset to range. If you are pulling all your rows into a recordset and just want to output it into a worksheet you can use the following:

```
Public Sub SearchNames()

    Dim oResources As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oDal As New clsDAL

    Set oResources = oDal.GetReadonlyRS("SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [ResourceTasks$]") 'where Date >= **Drop date from selection here**  and Date < **Drop date from selection here**  'where Active like TRUE ")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Range("A31").CopyFromRecordset Data:=oResources
    oResources.Close
    Set oResources = Nothing

    oDal.closeFile
    Set oDal = Nothing

    '! close connection and file

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried similar way to make it; and still it complains about this Insert statement

Comment: Ohh sorry, I had not reviewed the query. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: It kinda confuses me that you state that you are inserting from one Excel sheet to another but I only see you writing a hard-coded row of values to your target workbook. Where is it that you are pulling from the source workbook? If you would query the whole sheet through a select, then you could drop it into a recordset and then write to target workbook.

Comment: yes, I know it looks confusing. I have 2 excel files; 1st one is "Tracker" - it's my "db" with 3 tabs(names, tasks and ResourceTasks); I select based on date condition data from ResourceTasks and load it into "Master" excel file, after, if needed, user should be able to modify this selected data, and append it back to ResourceTasks tab; And Select part of this plan works fine; For now i'm trying to make this Insert part to work

Comment: Can you show code where you select or pull data from Resource Tasks? Is that not a select already? Why don't you drop that select into a recordset and then write to target?

Comment: I added it to base post; I'm not so familiar with this technology yet; Can you add some details to this idea with writing to target? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax problem with the `Date` field in the query.

> & CDate("24 / 5 / 2017") &...

A date should be either enclosed with `#`, or, Excel-specific, can be passed as a number.

First option:

```
... VALUES ('Name11', 'task2', #24/5/2017#, 0.50)"
'                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Second option:

```
... VALUES ('Name11', 'task2'," & CDbl(DateSerial(2017, 5, 24)) & ", 0.50)"
'                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also if `ResourceTasks` is a worksheet, it should be referenced in the query as `[ResourceTasks$]`

```
INSERT INTO [ResourceTasks$] VALUES...
```

Comment: all 3 options were tasted before and there is no difference in result; Can I have some problem with drivers, or dll or whatever else MS related problems ?

Comment: @VladimirZaguzin what is `ResourceTasks`, a worksheet? then should be used as `[ResourceTasks$]`.

Comment: yes, ResourceTasks is a worksheet in a workbook that i use as DB; for a moment I was like "how could I miss it" but even with this [ResourceTasks$] format, I still see the same error message