# Insert Data into Excel File using SQL

Tags: sql, vba

Im using SQL statement to insert some date in excel. but got error.

I tried

```
INSERT INTO  Sheet1$ (Contribution Month, Serial, Name, Contributions Type, Amount, Status) 
VALUES (01/09/2018, 353660, BRUIN NOEL, Employer, -694.58, open)

INSERT INTO  Sheet1 (Contribution Month, Serial, Name, Contributions Type, Amount, Status) 
VALUES (01/09/2018, 353660, BRUIN NOEL, Employer, -694.58, open)

INSERT INTO  Sheet1$ (Contribution Month, Serial, Name, Contributions Type, Amount, Status) 
VALUES ('01/09/2018', '353660', 'BRUIN NOEL', 'Employer', '-694.58', 'open')

INSERT INTO  Sheet1 (Contribution Month, Serial, Name, Contributions Type, Amount, Status) 
VALUES ('01/09/2018', '353660', 'BRUIN NOEL', 'Employer', '-694.58', 'open')
```

Any corrections?

Comment: Have you tried `VALUES ('01/09/2018', 353660, 'BRUIN NOEL', 'Employer', -694.58, 'open')`?

Comment: yes, I tried also to update one data first and it is having error.

Comment: Error: Syntax Error

Comment: [Contribution Month] if the field name has spaces

Comment: Try to use OPENROWSET.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822576/excel-into-sql-server-with-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0 Hope this can help you!

Comment: ok. let me try that one!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329909/insert-data-from-one-excel-file-to-another-one-using-adodb

Answer (score 0):

Try the follwing code:

```
INSERT INTO  [Sheet1$] ([Contribution Month], [Serial], [Name], [Contributions Type], [Amount], [Status]) 
VALUES ('01/09/2018', 353660, 'BRUIN NOEL', 'Employer', -694.58, 'open')
```

There are some characters missing. For sheet name `[]`, field name `[]` and their `''` string value.